# Updating nested data with raw mongodb

Tags: mongodb, push, meteor, updates

I have the following data structure:

```
Object
_id: "ca06ef84-5934-498e-9887-8a3241e713f2"
answers: Object
owner: "273b7291-df2b-494c-bd9b-64e71283447e"
Topic: "My Topic"
__proto__: Object
```

Where `answers` is:

```
1: Object
answer: "My Answer"
__proto__: Object
```

How can I use mongodb to push in n additional `answers` objects? Thus far I have something like this, which of course is completely wrong. Am I walking down the wrong path?

```
db.collection.update({},{"$push":{"answers":1{"hi":"new"}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({_id: <id>},{"$push":{"answers":{"hi":"new"}}})
```

or you can use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) instead $push to add only unique answers. Also take a look on ['upsert'](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-upsert) parameter to add new topics without checking it existance.